# I am trying to display list of blog documents in to react app and our backend is express js and the database is mongodb but i can't

Tags: node.js, reactjs, arrays, express, mern

I am trying to display list of blog documents in to react app and our backend is express js and the database is mongodb but i can't recieve the send as on object from express js and when i test it with postman the backend sends perfectly .i have a collection called blogs and each blog is stored in this collection as a document .

> this is router which routes to specfic route for this situation /blogList is called

```
const {Router} = require ('express');
const blogController = require('../controllers/blogController');
const router = Router();

router.get('/login',blogController.login_get);
router.post('/login',blogController.login_post);
router.get('/signup',blogController.signup_get);
router.post('/signup',blogController.signup_post);
router.post('/createBlog',blogController.blog_post);
router.get('/blogList',blogController.blog_get);
module.exports = router;
```

> this is blogcontroller file which contains the actual code that is executed for specifc , i displayed only the "blogController.blog_post" function which is the one we need for now. the function returns a json object which the key is blogListAll and the value is an array of  blog document from a mongo database . the documents has title,body and author and _id entity.

```
module.exports.blog_get = async (req, res) => {
// this blogList returns array of documents
const blogList = await blogModel.find({});
res.status(200).json({blogListAll:blogList});
// i printed to console to test it with postman
console.log(blogList) 
}
```

> this is a react component called blogList and which tries to fecth an array and assign that array to a state value called "blogs" and map through that array and display only author and title as alist .

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const BlogList = () => {
const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
fetch("http://localhost:5000/blogList")
  .then((res) => res.json)
  .then((data) => {
    // trying to access array from json object
    // object blogListAll:array_data
    // i tried to assign an array to blog
    setBlogs(data.blogListAll);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  }, []);
  return (
<div className="blog-list">
  <h2>List of Blog</h2>
   <p>{blogs.map((blog)=> (
    <div key={blog._id}>
        <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
        <p>{blog.author}</p>
    </div>
  ))}</p> 
</div>
);
};
export default BlogList;
```

> this is the result after i tested it with postman which says backend works correctly
> [image]

the problem is

1. I can't recieve that array and assign it
2. I can't display it as alist
3. It says this when I run it:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')